# Prove that exists $g\in G$ such that $1-\frac{|A \cup ( B+g)|}{|G|} \leq \left(1-\frac{|A|}{|G|}\right)\left(1-\frac{|B|}{|G|}\right)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ a finite commutative group and   $A,B\subset G$ non empty. Prove that exists $g\in G$ such that $$1-\frac{|A \cup ( B+g)|}{|G|} \leq \left(1-\frac{|A|}{|G|}\right)\left(1-\frac{|B|}{|G|}\right)$$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thanks so much, I´m reading about it, I´m glad with you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that if you sum the left hand side of your inequality over all $g\in G$, you obtain
$$\sum_{g\in G}\left(1-\frac{|A\cup (B+g)|}{|G|}\right)=|G|-\sum_{g\in G}\frac{|A\cup (B+g)|}{|G|}$$
and using the identity $|X\cup Y|=|X|+|Y|-|X\cap Y|$, the above becomes
$$=|G|-\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}|A|-\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G}|B+g|+ \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}| A\cap (B+g)|$$
and noting that $|B+g|\ge|B|$, we obtain the upper bound
$$\le |G|-|A|-|B|+ \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}| A\cap (B+g)|$$
then realizing that the elements of $A\cap (B+g)$ are precisely those $(a,b)\in A\times B$ such that $a=b+g$ (not counting multiplicities, and hence there can be no more than $|A\times B|=|A||B|$ such elements over all $g\in G$) we arrive at
$$\le |G|-|A|-|B|+ \frac{1}{|G|}|A||B|$$
$$=|G|\left(1-\frac{|A|}{|G|}\right)\left(1-\frac{|B|}{|G|}\right)\,.$$
Comparing this to the right hand side of your inequality, the just-derived inequality would be a contradiction if the left hand side of your inequality were always greater than the right hand side for each $g\in G$.